# How to properly debug websites on the Samsung Browser

Tags: samsung-internet-browser

The Samsung Browser is not Chrome nor Android stock browser. And our webdev teams have some bugs that only show up on this specific browser.

Is there any way I can remotely debug it as I can do with Chrome or Firefox? Either on an emulator or a real device.

Comment: it's the "Internet" app on samsung devices. user agent string is `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; GT-P5210 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.30` my best guess is the stock android browser with some samsung bugs added

Answer (score 15):

The new **Samsung Internet** browser is based on the Chromium browser and thus supports its remote debugging interface.

1. Enable USB debugging on your device as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app).
2. Then connect your device via USB (Oh, surprise!).
3. Visit `chrome://inspect` on your computers Google Chrome browser and you will be guided to create the connection:

   [image: Chrome inspect]
4. Then you just have to click on the devices `inspect` link and an developer tools window will pop up.

More info like why there is an Samsung Internet Browser at all can be found [here](https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/introducing-samsung-internet-for-developers-6c3a3be42f72).

Answer (score 1):

Type `about:debug` or `about:console` in a new tab (one of these will work), then try to send something to the `console.log` in your JavaScript.

At the top of your page will appear "SHOW JAVASCRIPT CONSOLE", click on it and you will have the console log with the possible error message you are looking for.

Comment: This doesn't work on my Galaxy Tab A (2016).

Comment: this does not work on s8+